# How to set mysql datediff result into row list

Tags: mysql

I would like to ask you guys about something about DateDiff in MySQL.

for example, here is some code of mysql datediff.

```
select datediff('2015-10-11', '2015-10-15') as Diffdate
```

and the result would be

```
| DiffDate |
------------
|       4  |
------------
```

so, my question is, how do I make the Diffdate result into some kind of row numbers from 1 to the result of diffDate?

this is the result that I want.

```
| DiffDate |
------------
|       1  |
|       2  |
|       3  |
|       4  |
------------
```

thank you in advance

Comment: Typically, this would be handled in application level code.

Comment: @Strawberry agree. Aji, can i know the reason why you want to do this?

Comment: if I should explain, i want to retrieve a kind of "select count(somecolumn) from table where date between ......", and I also want to retrieve the missing date, if there are any missing date from my select query. sorry for my bad in english

Comment: @strawberry ah, i've had thought about it before, but I still cant get any way to it :(

Answer (score 1):

The trick is first to select numbers from 1 to 31:

```
 select n.x from 
     (Select 1 x
      union select 2 x
     union select 3 x
...
       union select 31 x) n ,
     (select datediff('2015-10-15', '2015-10-11') as Diffdate) d
     where n.x <= d.Diffdate
```

I the example above should `datediff('2015-10-11', '2015-10-15')` is -4: that's why i have exchanged the args order.

Comment: That should work ;) (I have forgoten the first select)

Comment: ah, it works. but how if the days is more than 30? is there any way to make it short? I mean the query

Comment: This query will obviously only work for finite numbers: I think you should take @strawberry  advice and do it in the application level code. In Sql you would have to write a script, not a simple query.